# svn command to see who in which revision number omments some code

Tags: shell, svn, grep

I 'd like to discover who comments some code in which revision number,  I used below shell command

```
svn log com/foo/web/action/BarAction.java | egrep -o "r[0-9]+" | head -n 5       
r19793
r13653
r13240
r12259
r12113

svn log com/foo/web/action/BarAction.java | egrep -o "r[0-9]+" | head -n 5 | xargs -i svn cat -{} com/foo/web/action/BarAction.java | grep kfyhq

//                      sendToList.add("kfyhq@foo.com");
//                      sendToList.add("kfyhq@foo.com");
                    sendToList.add("kfyhq@foo.com");
                    sendToList.add("kfyhq@foo.com");
```

but it does not show revision number,  How could let it show revision number too, e.g.

```
 //                     sendToList.add("kfyhq@foo.com"); r13653
                    sendToList.add("kfyhq@foo.com"); r13240
```

Comment: `svn blame com/foo/web/action/BarAction.java | | grep kfyhq `?

Comment: Hi, I tried your way and only display my latest modify that is cancel the comments

Comment: Now decrease revision by 1 and perform svn blame -r REV...`

Comment: yeah, it works. My latest revision number is 19880, then I used this command `svn blame -r 19879 com/foo/web/action/BarAction.java | grep kfyhq` got who in which revision number comment this code.